# Events not triggering in foreignObject for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, mouseevent

Trying to create an elaborate menu-system using svg's foreignObject I came across what seems to be a bug in Firefox. When the my sub-meny items extended outside of my foreignObject's container size my *mouseleave event* triggered. I made a simpler example to show the problem using mouse click events.

When browsing in Chrome there is no problem, but in Firefox (neither latest nor beta) I cannot get it to trigger. Has anyone ever seen this problem before, and have any clues on how to solve it?

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wigglemaster/x789bcg0/2/)

#### HTML

```
<svg>
    <foreignObject width="100px" height="100px" style="overflow:visible">
        <div top=0px id="target" onclick='javascript:alert("hi");'></div>
        <div top=0px id="foborder" onclick='javascript:alert("hi");'></div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

#### CSS

```
svg #target {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #dd0;
    position:absolute;
}
svg #foborder {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: raise a bug in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG

Comment: I was looking for a workaround, but yes, I'll create a bug report as well. Thanks

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Firefox and as such I am marking this as solved

Comment: This bug is still reproducible in the latest FF (47.0) under win/lin. So you mean there's no solution to this?

Comment: Yup. Until the bug is fixed I found no solution for this :(